# drag a textarea when the cursor is inside the control

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am making a textarea draggable using jquery UI....basically im making a div draggable and in that div is my textarea. when u drag the div the textarea drags too. the problem is that if my mouse pointer is inside the textarea, and i try to drag the control, it fails. so basically when the pointer changes the shape from arrow to that symbol when u are writting text( i dont know wats the name of the shape) the dragging donot occur! i think i can understand that since the text area is in editable mode, and when u click inside, the jquery drag method might not be invoked...but i think there shud be a solution to this!

thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to easily get around this is to mimic a window UI component where the top side bar is the handle for the dragging and the content is not.

Refer to the corresponding section of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle) for further information

Comment: thanks for the suggestion....this is wat im doing rite nw :) but it dint look very professional

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the textarea the you could simply mask it with another div, or set it to disabled. However, if you do need the textarea then you've got yourself a usability issue as you'd never be able to highlight text inside the textarea if you did manage to make it draggable.